# SQL BCP invalid object name ##Labels

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bcp

I'm having trouble with BCP. It keeps saying invalid object name ##Labels despite me creating a global table. What am I doing wrong please?

The code is: -

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)       

SET @BatchNo = 'abc123'

DECLARE @test TABLE(A varchar(max),B varchar(max),C varchar(max),D varchar(max),E varchar(max),F varchar(max),G varchar(max),H varchar(max),I varchar(max),J varchar(max))

insert into @test values ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10')

SELECT * INTO ##Labels FROM @test       

SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM ##Labels'

DECLARE @TMPfile varchar(25)
DECLARE @folder varchar(128)
DECLARE @LabelDir varchar(128)
DECLARE @template varchar(25)
DECLARE @FinalFile varchar(40)
DECLARE @cmdstr varchar(300)


SET @TMPfile = @BatchNo + '.tmp'                            
--Trigger folder
SET @folder = '\\WIN-0H\LABELLING\XFER\'                            
--Print Directive Folder
SET @LabelDir = '\\WIN-0H\DIR\'
--Label Data Template
SET @template = 'cl.csv'
--Fine output file
SET @FinalFile = @BatchNo + '.CHLABEL'

--Bulk Copy Query to csv temp file
SET @cmdstr = 'bcp "' + @SQL + '" QUERYout ' + @folder + @TMPfile + ' -c -t "," -T'
SELECT * FROM ##Labels
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmdstr 
PRINT @cmdstr 

--join the label csv template to the actual data
SET @cmdstr = 'copy /Y /B ' + @LabelDir + @template + ' + ' + @folder + @TMPfile + ' ' + @folder + @FinalFile
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmdstr
PRINT @cmdstr 

--Remove all temporary files
SET @cmdstr = 'del ' + @folder + @TMPfile
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmdstr 
PRINT @cmdstr 
PRINT 'Im Printing'

DROP TABLE ##Labels
```

The error message is:

> Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid
>   object name '##Labels'.

Comment: Are you running this script against a named instance? BCP will connect to the local default instance unless you specify the `/S` parameter.

Comment: Hey Dan, No it's on the same instance. I'm just writing the script with sql manager on that instance using the SA account.

Comment: Is the instance you run the script against the default instance or is it a named instance?  The BCP command invoked via xp_cmdshell doesn't know what instance it was executed from, so the server/instance name needs to be specified if it's not the default instance.

Comment: well done that man. I didn't realise it was that disconnected to the script. Many Thanks that works great.

Answer (score 1):

The BCP command-line utility runs independently of the T-SQL script, even when inviked via xp_cmdshell.  It connects to the default instance on the same server it runs on unless the BCP `/S` parameter specifies otherwise.

In this case, the global temp table was created on the named instance where the script ran.  However, the BCP command connected to the default instance and the global temp table did not exist there (fortunately).